# Variable not change the valor in the thread

Tags: java, multithreading, protocols, network-protocols

I'm doing a routing protocol packets between nodes and I have the following issue that I think is related threads, which are overwriting the variables, but do not know how to fix it. I have the code where the error is as follows:

```
pclass nodosVecinos extends Thread {
public static int port = 0;
String num_Nodo = "";
byte[] buf = new byte[10000];
public synchronized void run() {
    DatagramPacket dP = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    DatagramSocket sK = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(port);
        sK = new DatagramSocket(this.port);//<-- Problem
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("problem node "+num_Nodo);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Node "+ num_Nodo +" up!"); // Nodo 1 encendido!
    while(true){
        try {
            sK.receive(dP);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Problem node , While");
        }
        System.out.println(buf.toString());

    }
}
public nodosVecinos (int puerto){
    port = puerto;
    num_Nodo = Integer.toString(port);
    num_Nodo = num_Nodo.substring(num_Nodo.length()-1,num_Nodo.length()); // 8001 => 1
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
}
```

}

i get out whit breackpoint :

```
8001 // <--- out in terminal
-1 // <--- Whit breackpoint and error.
```

I try write static the variable port but no go .

Thx for your help.

Edit:

The port is extern of synchronized , is class variable.

Comment: How port variable is set?

Comment: port is a variable of the class, so basically can be setted and managed outside your syncronized method.

Comment: I post full class code .

Answer (score 0):

How do you start the threads?
Maybe "synchronized" is the problem. It causes that the whole method is executed before a new thread can start, but this method is infinite.

Comment: yep , this is ever up.